# Repeating and incrementing a readline() user input x number of times

Tags: r

This function should take the integer that the user inputs in the first `readline()` prompt, and then run the next section of `readline()` inputs based on that integer.

If `numSampFolders` == 1, then it only requires one sample folder name, as per the code below. Similarly, if `numSampFolders` == 2, then it requires two sample folder names.

There must be a better way to write this than how I've set it up, though (and I don't really want to end up with dozens of `if()` statements just to cover every eventuality...). For example, if numSampFolders = 24, the code should ask the user, via `readline()`, to input 24 names and store those names as global variables. (I understand that this could be more easily done with `list.files()`, however there are folders in the same directory that are not required.)
Thanks for ideas.

```
set_params <- function(){
    numSampFolders <- (readline("How many sample folders are you using? "))
    numSampFolders <<- as.numeric(numSampFolders)
    if (numSampFolders == 1)
        SampFolder1 <<- readline("Enter the name of your only sample folder: ")
    if (numSampFolders == 2)
        SampFolder1 <<- readline("Enter the name of sample folder 1: ")
        SampFolder2 <<- readline("Enter the name of sample folder 2: ")
}
if(interactive()) set_params()
```

Comment: It'd be easier to ask users to supply a separate file with all of the sample folder names. It's the same amount of work for the user...

Comment: It probably would be for larger folder numbers, but if there are only two or three folders that wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to use `lapply` (or `sapply/for`) for iteration and the R verb `assign`. `assign` behaves like `<-`, and the trick to making `assign` behave like `<<-` is to specify the environment with `envir = .GlobalEnv`. See the following solution

```
set_params <- function(){
    numSampFolders <- (readline("How many sample folders are you using? "))
    numSampFolders <<- as.numeric(numSampFolders)
    if (numSampFolders == 1) {
        SampFolder1 <<- readline("Enter the name of your only sample folder: ")
    } else if (numSampFolders > 1) {
        lapply(seq_len(numSampFolders), function(i) assign(paste0("SampFolder", i), readline(paste0("Enter the name of sample folder ", i, ": ")), envir = .GlobalEnv))
    }
}
if(interactive()) set_params()
```

Here's the output of my console

```
ls()
# character(0)

# How many sample folders are you using? 2
# Enter the name of sample folder 1: ok
# Enter the name of sample folder 2: whatever
# [[1]]
# [1] "ok"

# [[2]]
# [1] "whatever"

ls()
# [1] "numSampFolders" "SampFolder1"    "SampFolder2"    "set_params"

SampFolder1  
# [1] "ok"
```

You may not like that `lapply` prints the values to the console (in this case, it's a side-effect). The following is what I'm referring to

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "ok"
```

In that case, you can use `purrr::walk` to loop without the side-effects.

```
library(purrr)
set_params <- function(){
    numSampFolders <- (readline("How many sample folders are you using? "))
    numSampFolders <<- as.numeric(numSampFolders)
    if (numSampFolders == 1) {
        SampFolder1 <<- readline("Enter the name of your only sample folder: ")
    } else if (numSampFolders > 1) {
        walk(seq_len(numSampFolders), function(i) assign(paste0("SampFolder", i), readline(paste0("Enter the name of sample folder ", i, ": ")), envir = .GlobalEnv))
    }
}

if(interactive()) set_params()
```